# Describing the base of a topology based on subbasis.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces, solution-verification

**Exercise.** For an ordered set $(X,\leq)$ the sets $A = \{y \in X : y \not \leqslant x\}$ and $B = \{y \in X: x \not \leqslant y\}$ with $x \in X$ are a subbase of the interval topology. In $\Bbb R^n$ the relation $\leq$ is defined by $x \leq y \Leftrightarrow x_i \leq y_i, \forall i \in [n]$. Show that under the interval topology $\mathcal{T}_k$ of $\Bbb R^k$ we have the following thesis:

> $\mathcal{T}_1$ is the Euclidian topology induced by the metric $d(x,y) = ||x-y||.$

**My attempt.** For a general case, let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, then the metric $d$ in $X$ generates the topology with base $\mathcal{B} = \{B_d(x,\epsilon): x \in X, \epsilon > 0\}$, where
\begin{align*}
 B_d(x,\epsilon) = \{y \in X: d(x,y) < \epsilon\}.
\end{align*}
So, the topology induced by the metric $d(x,y) = ||x-y|| = |x-y|$ (we are working in $\Bbb R$) as the base $\mathcal{B} = \{B_d(x,\epsilon): x \in \Bbb R, \epsilon > 0\}$, where
\begin{align*}
 B_d(x,\epsilon) = \{y \in \Bbb R : |x-y| < \epsilon\},
\end{align*}
and thus the base $\mathcal{B}$ corresponds to the intervals $]x,y[,\color{red}{]-\infty,x[,]x,+\infty[}$, com $x,y \in \Bbb R$. On the other hand, the base of the topology $\mathcal{T}_1$ in $\Bbb R$ corresponds to the collection of all finite intersections of subasis elements ,i.e., corresponds to:
\begin{align*}
 \mathcal{B}_{\mathcal{T}_1} = \bigcap_{1\leqslant i \leqslant k \\ 1 \leqslant j \leqslant k} \{A_i,B_j\},
\end{align*}
where $A_i = \{y \in \Bbb R: y > x_i\}$ and $B_j = \{y \in \Bbb R: y < x_j\}$ for some $x_i,x_j \in \Bbb R$. This obviously matches the previous open intervals in $\Bbb R$, proving what's wanted.

**My doubts.** Firstly, are the sets that I colored as red included in the topology generated by the metric $d$? I had some trouble deciding wheter to put them in or not. Secondly, is my approach to the finite intersection correct? Because if I take $i=j$ I get the set $\Bbb R\backslash\{x_i (=x_j)\}$ which is not included in the open intervals cited in the beggining? Thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: The usual topology on $\Bbb R$ includes many open sets that are not intervals, e.g. $\Bbb R$ \ $\{0\}$ and $]0,1[\cup ]2,3[$.  A base for a topology $T$ on a set $X$ is any $B\subseteq T$ such that any member of $T$ is the union of some member(s) of $B$.